# Как открыть окно не закрывая предыдущие?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Делаю программу для работы с *Excel*, только не знаю как открыть окно поверх предыдущего. 
Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки "**`поиск`**", открывалось поверх окно **win.py** и в строку поиска записывалось число и сохранялось в переменную "**`rows`**"

**main.py**

```
import sys
import pandas as pd 

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
QStackedWidget, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from UI.table import Ui_table
from UI.win import Ui_dialog



class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table, Ui_dialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self) 
    
    self.fname = None                                                            
    self.initUI()
    
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.addRow)                        
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.delRow)                        
    self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.exportToExcel)  
    self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.search)                                
    
def initUI(self):
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

def update(self):
    if not self.fname:                                                            
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка!', "Выберите Exсel файл")
        return                                                                  
    excel_file_path = self.fname                             
    worksheet_name = 'Лист1'                                     
    self.loadExcelData(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)

def open_file(self):
    self.fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  
        "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") 
    print(f'fname = {self.fname}')    
    
def loadExcelData(self, excel_file_path, worksheet_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)
    if df.size == 0:
        return

    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

    
    for row in df.iterrows():
        values = row[1]
        for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
            if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
            tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))

            self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 300)


def search(self):
    cols = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
    data = []
    rows = 4
    for rows in range(rows, rows+1):
        tmp = []
        for col in range(cols):
            try:
                tmp.append(self.tableWidget.item(rows,col).text())
            except:
                tmp.append('No data')
        data.append(tmp)
    for i in data: print(i)


   
def addRow(self):
    rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    if not rowPosition:
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите Exсel файл для добавления строки.')
        return     
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

def delRow(self):
    row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    if row == -1:
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите строку для удаления')
        return
    self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)


def exportToExcel(self):
    rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    if not rows:
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Нечего сохранять.')
        return      

    path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Сохранить Excel', '.', 'Excel(*.xlsx)')
    if not path:
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Не указан файл для сохранения.')
        return

    columnHeaders = []
    
    for j in range(self.tableWidget.model().columnCount()):
        columnHeaders.append(self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(j).text())

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnHeaders)

    
    for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
            df.at[row, columnHeaders[col]] = self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text()

    df.to_excel(path, index=False)
    msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Excel', 'Файл сохранен')        



if __name__ == '__main__': 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()
windows = QStackedWidget()

windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  
windows.setWindowTitle("")
windows.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**table.py**

```
class Ui_table(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1000, 684)
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 684))
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 342, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 811, 631))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 220, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 279, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 400, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
    self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 170, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.action.setObjectName("action")
    self.menu.addAction(self.action)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обновить"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "добавить"))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "удалить"))
    self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "сохранить"))
    self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "поиск"))
    self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
    self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть файл"))
```

**win.py**

```
class Ui_dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(221, 160)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 121, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 121, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 121, 16))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 221, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОК"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите номер строки"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я отметил для вас в какие строки надо внести изменения. Что будет не понятно - спросите.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from UI.table import Ui_table
class Ui_table(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 684)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 684))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 342, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 811, 631))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 220, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 279, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 400, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 170, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обновить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "добавить"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "удалить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "сохранить"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "поиск"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть файл"))
        
        
#from UI.win import Ui_dialog
class Ui_dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(221, 160)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 121, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 221, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОК"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите номер строки"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Dialog(QMainWindow, Ui_dialog):               #, Ui_dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):                            #, Ui_dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.fname = None                                                            
        self.initUI()
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.addRow)                        
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.delRow)                        
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.exportToExcel) 
        
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.dialog = Dialog()                                          # +++
        self.dialog.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.searchOk)           # +++
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

    def update(self):
        if not self.fname:                                                            
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка!', "Выберите Exсel файл")
            return                                                                  
        excel_file_path = self.fname                             
        worksheet_name = 'Лист1'                                     
        self.loadExcelData(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)

    def open_file(self):
        self.fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  
            "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") 
        print(f'fname = {self.fname}')    
        
    def loadExcelData(self, excel_file_path, worksheet_name):
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)
        if df.size == 0:
            return

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

        
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))

                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 300)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def search(self):
        self.dialog.show()
    
    def searchOk(self):  
        row = self.dialog.lineEdit.text()
        _rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        if not row.isdigit():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Укажите правильно строку.')
            self.dialog.hide()
            return
            
        if int(row) >= _rows:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Укажите правильно строку.')
            self.dialog.hide()
            return        
        self.dialog.hide()
        
        cols = self.tableWidget.columnCount()      
        data = []
        rows = int(row)                                                       # 4
        for rows in range(rows, rows+1):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
#                try:
                item = self.tableWidget.item(rows, col)
                if item:
                    tmp.append(self.tableWidget.item(rows, col).text())
#                except:
                else:
                    tmp.append('No data')
            data.append(tmp)
#        for i in data: print(i)
        print(* data)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       
    def addRow(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        if not rowPosition:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите Exсel файл для добавления строки.')
            return     
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

    def delRow(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите строку для удаления')
            return
        self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)


    def exportToExcel(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        if not rows:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Нечего сохранять.')
            return      

        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Сохранить Excel', '.', 'Excel(*.xlsx)')
        if not path:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Не указан файл для сохранения.')
            return

        columnHeaders = []
        
        for j in range(self.tableWidget.model().columnCount()):
            columnHeaders.append(self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(j).text())

        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnHeaders)

        
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                df.at[row, columnHeaders[col]] = self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text()

        df.to_excel(path, index=False)
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Excel', 'Файл сохранен')        


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()
    windows = QStackedWidget()

    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  
    windows.setWindowTitle("")
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как закрывать преведущие окно при открытии нового?

Comment: @grabhar  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide